# How to install our own template on TeXnicCenter?

Tags: templates, editors, texniccenter

I am lazy to type the following

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](6,6)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

every time I want to start drawing with PSTricks.

I am using TeXnicCenter and it provides its own templates. Shortly speaking, can I install my own templates such that they are available from TeXnicCenter?

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question (I'm not sure TeXnicCenter can do what you ask) but why don't you keep this template of yours somewhere safe (in a dedicated directory) and use it as a basis for producing a new document? Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @Jubobs: It is what I usually do everyday. I made the template read only so I have to save the copy of it with another name before start drawing. But I want a smarter way. :-)

Comment: Have you checked this: http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/doctemplates.html

Comment: Do you use Linux? You can create a script to open the editor with the template. I did one and just type on terminal `fastex` and then it opens TeXstudio with the same file to make tests.

Comment: @Sigur: I am a Windows user.

Comment: @PGFTricks, in this case you can do a `bat` file with some commands to open your editor with your template. I'm not expert using `bat` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can certainly be done.

## Step 1

Create a directory anywhere you like that will contain your templates. In theory you could probably use the `TeXnicCenter` default directory (in `Program Files`) but this may get overwritten when you update, so I would therefore recommend something like

```
C:\Users\chughes\Documents\textemplates`
```

Within this directory, *you must create sub-directories* that will give `TeXnicCenter` the details to create a tab when you go to insert the templates. I have used

```
C:\Users\chughes\Documents\textemplates\diagrams`
```

in the below, but you could use what you like. Now you can put your templates (`mypstrickstemplate.tex`, `mytikztemplate.tex`, etc) file in this directory.

## Step 2

Go to `Tools->Options->Directories` and click `Add` under the `Document template directories`

[image: screenshot]

## Using the template

When you want to use the template, simply go to `File-> New-> File from template`

[image]

## References

- http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/doctemplates.html
- http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/options.html#directory-options